# google maps and events

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to have the functionality to where I can mouseover and mouseout on markers and pop the infowindow up and auto close it. Then when a user clicks on a marker I disable the mouseout for that marker to display the infowindow until the user manually closes it. I want to add the mouseout back to the marker when the user clicks the close for the infowindow.

I have this code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    //setTimeout(function() { infowindow.close(); }, 3000);
    infowindow.close(map, marker);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);            
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'mouseout');
});
```

I'm trying to use the 'click' event to disable the 'mouseout'. The above works. Now I want to add back the 'mouseout' event after the infowindow is closed using the 'closeclick' below.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', "");
});
```

I'm not sure how to do it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and thought I'd share:

```
function attachData(marker, number) {
    //snipped code that adds the events that are removed in closeMarker
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
            closeMarker(marker, number);
    });
}
```

The closeMarker function clears all current events and adds them back by calling the attachData function.

```
function closeMarker(marker, number) {
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'mouseover');
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'mouseout');
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'click');
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'closeclick');
        attachData(marker, number);
    }
```